# How to select last updated row until specific date?

Tags: sql

We have three ProductIDs and their prices are changing by Date

```
ProductID   Price       Date
1            100      2016-06-01
2            50       2016-06-05
3            10       2016-06-10
2            60       2016-06-15
1            110      2016-06-20
3            20       2016-06-25
```

How to select **only** last updated Price per each ProductID until 2016-06-20 inclusive to get the next output:

```
ProductID   Price
3            10
2            60
1            110
```

I searched for answer but could't find the specific one.

Comment: Tg your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Have a sub-query that returns each ProductID's last date (until 2016-06-20). Join with that result:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join (select ProductID, max(Date) Date
        from tablename
        where Date <= '2016-06-20'
        group by ProductID) t2
    on t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID and t1.Date = t2.Date
```

ANSI SQL has `date` as reserved word, so you may need to delimit that column as `"Date"`. Also ANSI SQL has date literals as `date '2016-06-20'`.